# jQuery - Mobile Chrome - is.Parent

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

So I have a jQuery script that fires fine in PC Chrome but is broken in the Chrome Mobile App.  The following function fires within Mobile Chrome:

```
$("tr").live("click tap", function itinerary(){
```

I know this because I've set and moved an alert script to find where this issue is:

```
alert("Works");
```

So I've narrowed down where the issue is, and it is when I try to fire a conditional is.Parent script:

```
 if ( parent.is( "td.gfield_list_cell.gfield_list_53_cell3" ) ){
```

Again the previous is.Parent does work within Chrome on a PC, but not Chrome Mobile.  Any thoughts on how I can clean it up or what the issue might be?

Thanks!

**1/23 UPDATE**
Folks have asked for the code so here it is.  There is a lot going on, plus I am fairly new to jQuery.  I am using jQuery to target and update a Gravity Forms List Field.  The following fires on a PC but does not on a mobile device.  I've marked where it seems to be stalling up

```
$(document.body).on("click tap", "#field_35_53 > div.ginput_container.ginput_container_list.ginput_list > table > tbody > tr", function(){

    var date = $('#input_35_28').val();
    var target = $( event.target );
    var parent = $( event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode );
    var child = $( event.target.parentNode );
    var index = $( "tr" ).index(this);
    var company = $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell3 select option:selected").text();
    var feature = $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell4 select option:selected").val();

    $("tr").eq( index ).find("td.gfield_list_53_cell3").each(function featurepop() {
    if ( parent.is( "td.gfield_list_cell.gfield_list_53_cell3" ) ){
    if( ('td.gfield_list_cell.gfield_list_53_cell4 > input[type="text"]') && ( company !== "**HOTEL**" ) ){
        $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell2 input").val("");
        $( 'td.gfield_list_cell.gfield_list_53_cell4 > input[type="text"]' ).replaceWith( '<select title="Item/Task/Feature" name="input_53[]" style="display: block;"><option value="Custom" class="selected" selected="selected">Select Feature</option></select>' );
        $( 'td.gfield_list_cell.gfield_list_53_cell13 > input[type="text"]' ).replaceWith( '<input aria-label="Other" type="checkbox" name="input_53[]" value="" tableindex="60"><label id="label_35_53_13_1">Fee</label></input>' );
    }
//jQuery fires on Mobile Chrome up to here 
        var data1 = {
            'action': 'feature_pop',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'type' : 'json',
            'feature_name': feature,
            'company_name': company
        };
//Here is where it stops working in Mobile Chrome
    alert("boom");
        var json = jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data1, function(response_a) {
        }).done(function(chain){
            var var1 = $("tr").eq( index ).find("td.gfield_list_cell.gfield_list_53_cell3 > select option:selected").text();
            var var2 = $("tr").eq( index ).find("td.gfield_list_cell.gfield_list_53_cell2 > input").val();

                if( ( var1 == "**HOTEL**" ) && ( ! var2 ) ){
                    $( "tr" ).eq( index ).find( "td.gfield_list_53_cell2 input" ).val( "5:00 pm" );
                }

                if( var1 == '**HOTEL**' ){
                    $( 'td.gfield_list_cell.gfield_list_53_cell4 > select' ).replaceWith( '<input aria-label="Item/Task/Feature" autocomplete="new-password" type="text" name="input_53[]" value=""></input>' );
                }

            $("tr").eq( index ).find("td.gfield_list_53_cell5 input").val("");
            $("tr").eq( index ).find("td.gfield_list_53_cell6 input").val("");
            $("tr").eq( index ).find("td.gfield_list_53_cell7 input").val("");
            $("tr").eq( index ).find("td.gfield_list_53_cell8 input").val("");
            $("tr").eq( index ).find("td.gfield_list_53_cell9 input").val("");
            $("tr").eq( index ).find("td.gfield_list_53_cell10 input").val("");
            $("tr").eq( index ).find("td.gfield_list_53_cell11 input").val("");
            $("tr").eq( index ).find("td.gfield_list_53_cell12 input").val("");
            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell4 select").empty();
            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell4 select .chosen-results").empty();

            $.each(chain, function(i, item) {
                $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell4 select").append('<option value="' + chain[i].choices + '">' + chain[i].choices + '</option>');
                $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell4 .chosen-results").append('<li>' + chain[i].choices + '</li>');
            });
            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell4 select").prepend('<option value="Custom" class="selected">Select Feature</option>');
            $("tr").eq( index ).find('select option[value="Custom"]').attr("selected",true);
            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell4").val( 'Select a Feature' );
            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell4 select").attr('style', 'display: block;');
            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell4 option").attr('class', 'selected');
            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell4 div[Title='Company']").attr('class', 'chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-container-active');
            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell4 div a").removeClass('chosen-default');
        });
}
    });

    $("tr").eq( index ).find("td.gfield_list_53_cell4").each(function() {
        if ( child.is( "td.gfield_list_cell.gfield_list_53_cell4" ) ){
        var data2 = {
            'action': 'data_pop',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'feature_name': feature,
            'company_name': company
        };

        var json = jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data2, function(response_b) {
        }).done(function(getdata){
            getdata.sort;

            if(getdata.time){
                $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell2 input").val("");
                $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell2 input").val( getdata.time );
            }

            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell5 input").val("");
            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell5 input").val( getdata.description );
            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell6 input").val("");

            if((typeof getdata.address1 != "undefined") && (getdata.address1 != "")){
                $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell6 input").val( getdata.address1 + " " + getdata.address2 + ", " + getdata.address3 + ", " + getdata.address4 + ", " + getdata.address5 );
            }

            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell7 input").val("");
            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell8 input").val("");
            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell9 input").val("");
            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell10 input").val("");
            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell10 input").val( getdata.phone );
            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell11 input").val("");;
            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell11 input").val( getdata.website );
            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell12 input").val("");
            $("tr").eq( index ).find(".gfield_list_53_cell12 input").val( getdata.cancel );         

            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? `live()` was deprecated and removed nearly 7 years ago

Comment: What exactly is an "is.parent script" ?

Comment: Thanks Roy & Taplar, ROY I'm using 1.4.1 and had moved to update it, but was concerned about issues it might cause with other scripts.  I've tried to get the .on script to do the same thing. but haven't been able to. TAPLAR, you know... I'm not exactly sure ^.^ I found it when trying to query my json, but can't remember which website that was.  All I know is it works in Chrome.  What would you use to query a json parent?

Comment: that is `parent` We need to see all your code

Comment: Sorry, got distracted with another issue.  parent.is makes use of the .is() filter.  https://api.jquery.com/is/#is-selector

I think I've solved that, but now I'm not able to get past an array.  I'll be updating above shortly.